# Replace multiple variables in a string sql query with actual values in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have the following SQL query as string,

```sql
string SQL = SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [dbo].[Incident] INNER JOIN dbo.IncidentNotification on Incident.IncidentID = IncidentNotification.IncidentID WHERE Incident.IncidentID = ?IncidentId? AND Incident.UserId = ?UserId?
```

I would like to replace it with

```sql
sql = SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [dbo].[Incident] INNER JOIN dbo.IncidentNotification on Incident.IncidentID = IncidentNotification.IncidentID WHERE Incident.IncidentID = 943434 AND Incident.UserId = '543'
```

There could be more variables like this, how should I go about this?

Comment: Use parameters.

Comment: Need an attempt

Comment: Why not use an ORM like Entity Framework or [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper)?

Answer (score 2):

One generally uses [SqlCommandBuilder Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) to build sql commands. With its structure it allows for replacement of variables before the execution of the command. Plus it helps avoid SQL Injection in most situations.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have mentioned, using SqlCommandBuilder or an ORM would be the suggested best practice.

But to directly answer your question, you wouldn't replace the variables (that's the point of variables), you should provide values for them.

```
var incidentId = 1345;
var userId = 6789;

var dangerousSQLStatement = $"SELECT * FROM IncidentTable Where Incidient.IncidentID = {incidentId} AND Incidient.UserId = {userId}";
```

See the documentation for further information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0